# Is this the real definition of an ordinal number?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I have to prove that if $\alpha$ is ordinal and $\beta \in \alpha$ then $\beta$ is oridinal.
To do this I wanted to prove that for every $x\in\beta$, $x\in\alpha$.

This seems like it should be true, but given the definition of ordinal numbers I have in my textbook, it doesn't seem so. It states the following

"A set $x$ is an ordinal number if $(a, \in)$ is transitive and well-ordered". Firstly, I'm pretty sure that a well-order implies transitivity, but that's not the problem here.

I can construct a set like $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ which is well-ordered with the $\in$ relation, but $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and $\{\emptyset\}\notin\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$.

Is this definition wrong, or does this property really not hold for ordinals? Or maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Transitivity is exactly the property that if $\beta\in \alpha$ and $\gamma\in \beta$, then $\gamma\in \alpha$.  This does not hold for all well-ordered sets (if you give such an example, it is necessarily then not an ordinal).

Comment: @Luka Horvat: your definition is not complete. an ordinal $\alpha$ must additionally satisfy the following property: if $x,y\in \alpha$, then $x=y$ or $x \in y$ or $y \in x$.

Comment: @russoo That is part of the definition of a (strict) well-order.

Comment: @Hayden Ok. Then my comment is waste. (However, I have seen authors which also allow partial orders to be well-orders.)

Comment: @Pp.. How is it not transitive? It only has two elements so the implication of transitivity is true because the assumption that there are $x, y, z$ such that $x\in y$ and $y\in z$ is false.

Comment: @Hayden Is my example not transitive?

Comment: @LukaHorvat I wrote it wrong. But yes, it is not transitive. The element $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is not a subset of the set. Transitive means every element is a subset.

Comment: @Pp.. I don't follow. I thought transitive means only that $(x<y,y<z)=> x < z$ which is true for my set.

Comment: @LukaHorvat In this case they mean the set is a transitive set, rather than the order being transitive. A transitive set is a set where its elements are also subsets.

Comment: Luka, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106768/difference-between-a-criteria-of-well-ordered-and-transitive-in-terms-of-an-ordi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition is correct and here is the proof you are looking for: Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal and let $\beta \in \alpha$. We show that $\beta$ has the two properties you mentioned:

Well-ordering: Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of $\beta$. From the transitivity of $\alpha$, it follows that $X \subseteq \alpha$ and since $\alpha$ is well-ordered, $X$ must contain a least element. Now, we show that the order $\in$ is total in $\beta$. Assume that $x,y \in \beta$. By the transitivity of $\alpha$, we have $x,y \in \alpha$ and therefore $x=y$, $x\in y$ or $y \in x$. Therefore, $\beta$ is a well-order.

Transitivity: Assume $x \in y \in \beta$. Then $x \in y \in \alpha$ and hence $x \in \alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is a well-order we must have $x=\beta$, $\beta \in x$ or $x \in \beta$ but the first two possibilities lead to a contradiction since $\beta$ is a well-order. Hence $x \in \beta$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Here is an inductive definition with which you can produce some ordinal numbers $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,...$:

$$\alpha_0=\emptyset$$ 
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\alpha_n \cup \{\alpha_n\}$$

You can verify that all these $\alpha_i$ are indeed ordinals. However, note that the above definition does not generate all ordinals.

Some examples:

$$\alpha_0=\emptyset$$

$$\alpha_1=\{\emptyset\}$$

$$\alpha_2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$

$$\alpha_3=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} \}$$